# Circle dividing a set of points

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, recurrence-relations, pigeonhole-principle, extremal-combinatorics

Suppose there be $2n+3$ points in a plane so that no 4 lie on a circle. Then there exists a circle through 3 points such that $n$ points lie inside the circle and the rest $n$ points lie outside that circle.

I solved it for five points. But can anyone suggest any idea to solve this problem by pigeonhole principle or recurrence? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you do it for $n=1$ ?

Comment: You haven't done a google search... I found instantly [this](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/scircles.shtml) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18734757/5802041)

Comment: Problem 3.1.7, page 61 in Mathematical Olympiad Challenges by Titu Andreescu & Razvan Gelca. The problem was for the IMO 1993.

Comment: Problem $24$ of chapter $3$ in the book problem solving strategies by Arthur Engel

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/18734757/14212297

Answer (score 2):

In $2n+3$ points, we can always choose two points say $A$ and $B$ so that all the 2n+1 points lie on one side of AB. Label the other $2n+1$ points as  $P_1, P_2, ..., P_{2n+1}$. Without loss of generality, we can assume
$$\angle AP_1B < \angle AP_2B < \angle AP_3B ...<\angle AP_nB < \angle AP_{n+1}B <\angle AP_{n+2}B <...\angle AP_{2n+1}B.$$ We choose $A, B, P_{n+1}$ as three points through which the circle passes. $P_1, P_2, ...P_n$ lie inside the circle and $P_{n+2}, P_{n+3}, ...P_{2n+1}$ lie outside the circle.